# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS jammy - adding "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" 403 Forbidden

Tags: apt, package-management

I am totally stuck on installing kube packages and hoping someone here could shed some light.

I am running Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 LTS Jammy

I started with `$ sudo apt update &&  sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release`

^^ this  worked

I then did `$sudo apt-get upgrade`

Installed docker and it all went fine until I got to these packages, and for three days I can't solve it. Keep reading and I'll explain.

We are attempting to setup a Kubernetes cluster.

I need to install kubelet kubeadm kubectl
But it seems I am following old docs or Kubernetes is badly maintained. I wish I  knew. :)

so I added the repo

```
echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-jammy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
```

First thing I see is I got certificate issues when running apt update.

I then solved that with:

```
curl -sS https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmour -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cloud.google.gpg
```

Updated my kubernetes.list with this:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/apt-key.gpg.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-jammy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
```

I then got a forbidden 403 error, and then realised the folder did not exist in the source url "https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists"

So I changed it to Xenial as I have seen a few guides where it has apparently worked on jammy.
for example:

https://www.vladimircicovic.com/2022/08/kubernetes-setup-on-ubuntu-2204-lts-jammy-jellyfish

So removed my source and created  this one:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/apt-key.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
```

But I am still getting forbidden.

```
Err:4 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 142.250.178.14 443]
```

Does any know of an easier way to install Kubernetes cluster?

Any help would be appreciated
Chadley

Comment: Can you please format the code in your post? Refer this: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Xenial is 16.04 a long gone EOL version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

So after much struggling, I tried apt update
and got output like this:

```
Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 142.250.178.14 443]
Fetched 324 kB in 7s (44.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.kubernetes.io/dists/kubernetes-xenial/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 142.250.178.14 443]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And this lead me to assume that IP was blocked and that it wasn't actually a certificate error.
Our firewall team added the IP to the allow list for the machine and the error has gone.
The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case  [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/release/issues/1982#issuecomment-1415573798)  works

```
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo dd status=none of=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
sudo apt update
```